# Parallel and non-parallel matlab's script - use of parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am currently using MATLAB 2013b and I want to design a script which can work with and without parallelism. In the previous version of MATLAB, I used `parfor` command in place of `for` command. The parallelism was activated only when I need it by using `matlabpool` command. In my current MATLAB's version I am surprised because when I use `parfor` whithout `matlabpool` the parallel pool starts.

One solution could to write some loops to deal with parallel and non-parallel version but to do this it takes a long time.

So I am looking for one solution to use `parfor` in parallel and non-parallel context.

Comment: Turning `parfor`s into classical `for`s is also great for debugging. I was looking exactly for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options: firstly, you can use the [Parallel Preferences](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parallel-preferences.html) to disable auto-creation of pools. Secondly, you can use the optional second argument to [PARFOR](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parfor.html) to choose when to go parallel. For example:

```
wantParallel = (rand() > 0.5); % or however you want to choose
if wantParallel
    workersArg = Inf; % Use all workers
else
    workersArg = 0; % No workers, do not open pool
end
parfor (idx = 1:N, workersArg)
    x(idx) = doStuff(...);
end
```

Comment: No it does not - PARFOR is included with MATLAB (it runs serially though).